# Puppeteer - wait for generated page to be fully loaded before taking screenshot

Tags: puppeteer, google-font-api

I'm using puppeteer to convert some HTML to PNG using the `screenshot` method.

First, I fetch some SVG, then I create a page, and set the SVG as page content.

```js
fetch(url)
  .then(data => data.text())
  .then((svgText) => {
    // res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    const $ = cheerio.load(svgText)
    return $.html()
  })
  .then(async (html) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setContent(html)

    const file = await page.screenshot()
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    await browser.close()
    res.send(file)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    logger.log({
      level: 'error', message: 'GET /product', err
    })
  })
})
```

The problem is, texts in my SVG includes a specific font. This font is loaded using the @import CSS tag. If I set my method to return the HTML, the fonts are loaded, then, after a slight delay, they get applied to my texts. Unfortunately, when using the `screenshot` method, my texts are not styled anymore. I suppose it is because the screenshot is taken before the fonts are loaded and applied, therefore rendering a text with a fallback font.

Is there a way to make sure that the page is completely rendered before taking the screenshot ?

I tried using the page.on('load') event listener, but this doesn't change anything the script just runs forever.

Comment: have you tried setting `waitUntil` with different options on `setContent`?

Comment: It seems a bit hacky, but you can `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200))` in between when you `setContent` and `screenshot`. See this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1209741/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-page-n-seconds-after-page-is-loaded-with-chrome-he